# No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5.2 app I have the following middleware inside `app/middleware` folder:

```
class CatchJsonParseErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError => error
      raise error unless env['HTTP_ACCEPT']&.match(/application\/json/)

      error_output = "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: #{error}"
      return [
        400, { "Content-Type" => "application/json" },
        [{ status: 400, error: error_output }.to_json]
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

In my `application.rb` file I have the following line:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters, "CatchJsonParseErrors")
```

When I try to start my app It returns following error:

```
`assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters (RuntimeError)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try requiring the file as autoloading may not work in this case? Also why return a JSON error object? The 400 response header tells the client that the request was malformed. I found it a huge antipattern to return response messages for things that end users can't really do anything about anyways.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it not works.

Comment: How did you solve this?  Also, code source: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see `ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters` middleware at [official Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#inspecting-middleware-stack) or [GitHub `rails` repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware). There is a module [`ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb) and it's just included to [`ActionDispatch::Request`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb) class. I guess as far as Rails (`ActionDispatch`) request object is ready you are free to verify/adjust it's params, and seems like this place is right after [`ActionDispatch::RequestId`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb#L25) middleware.